# Refreshing specific formulas in worksheet programmatically

Tags: c#, excel

I have developed an Excel plugin. It exposes three user-defined formulas to the Excel application. All that works fine. Now I need to add a refresh button that when clicked will refresh only those formulas in the worksheet. So in the button's click handler, what code do I need to write?

Using `Application.CalculateFull()` I can refresh all the formulas in the worksheet. Is there a way to refresh only specific formulas in the worksheet and not the entire worksheet?

Comment: It may help to specify what API you're using.

Comment: what do you mean by specific? you can select a cell and refresh it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Range("A3:C5").Calculate 'calculate all the cells from A3 to C5
```

OR

```
Range("A3").Calculate  'only calculate cell A3
```

Comment: Interesting. I haven't seen that before. I would imagine that Excel will calculate any cell that feeds into the calculation of the desired cells. So if A3 referred to A2, then A2 will also need to be calculated. Might also work for downstream calculations, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @gutarthrower: The formula calculation works only for directly dependent cells. i.e. if assume that A3 has formula where it sums A1 and A2, the selective calculation will work only if A1 & A2 has literal values. If A1 contains a formula, it won't be calculated in such a case. Because, one is asking Excel to evaluate formula for A3 *only*.

Answer (score 0):

> what i mean is i have developed an excel plugin.. It exposes
>   3 user defined formulas (x, y , z) to
>   excel application. All that works
>   fine.. Now i need to add a refresh
>   button that when clicked will refresh
>   only those (x, y and z) formulas in
>   the worksheet. So in the button's
>   click handler what code i need to
>   write?? Writing
>   Application.CalculateFull() refreshes
>   all the formulas. Thats not what i
>   want.

My top suggestion to achieve this would be to do a Find/Replace of the name of your user defined function (UDF) across the entire workbook. For example, if your UDF were named "MyFunction" you would want to replace "MyFunction(" with "MyFunction(".

Assuming that your Excel.Application reference were named 'excelApp', code to do a find/replace across all workbooks using C# could look as follows:

```
foreach (Excel.Workbook workbook in excelApp.Workbooks)
{
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet worksheet in workbook.Worksheets)
    {
        worksheet.Cells.Replace(
            "MyFunction(",
            "MyFunction(",
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            false,
            Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing);
    }
}
```

Other lesser ideas:

(a) Utilize a Real-Time Data (RTD) server. This is usually utilized for having data such as stock prices update frequently or continuously. This could also be used, however, to execute your "Refresh On Demand" approach. I personally think that this would be overkill in in this case, as Find/Replace works 100% perfectly and is far easier to implement, but RTD could definitely be used here. For an article on how to do this, see [Building Excel Real-Time Data Components in Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140061(office.10).aspx) it's geared towards VB.NET, not C#, but the principles are identical.

(b) Add another parameter to your function MyFunction(x, y, z, Refresh). By having each function reference the 'Refresh' cell, which can be placed on a hidden worksheet or hidden workbook, you can change the 'Refresh' cell to force all your functions to recalculate. The downside is that it requires this extra, dummy parameter.

(c) Stick with Application.CalculateFull(), as this is by far the easiest to code. I understand the performance issues, but it is extremely easy to code (just one line) and is 100% reliable.

Overall, I think that I would go with the Find/Replace approach. It is a clean, simple, and very effective technique for selective recalculations.

-- Mike